# Mark a Django Form in a FormSet as ignore

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to create a FormSet in which the first Form has an extra check to determine if it should be taken into account or not. The object is pretty simply:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    start_time = models.TimeField('start time')
```

I have multiple of these objects as Form in a FormSet. However, I set the start_time and the customer field with some javascript in the page. Now, when I change one of the other Entry Forms, I get a validation error on the empty one. Is there a way to check in the validation of the code if the form has an object associated with it and the description field is empty, that the set should just ignore this form?

I've tried overriding the clean() method of the Form, but I cannot find how to check the actual description field from there. Also, if I do find that this Form object should be ignored, how do I mark the form as 'ignore me'?

Or should I be doing this from the FormSet itself? If so, the self.forms is an immutable QueryDict, so it looks like I shouldn't modify that one. How else to mark one of the Forms as 'ignore it'?

Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the code which is evaluating the submitted formset? Now, when I change one of the other Entry Forms, I get a validation error on the empty one - What do you mean by this?. Seems, you should be able to check form.cleaned_data['description'].

Comment: I do not have any custom code to validate the submitted formset, I just get the formset with request.POST and do an is_valid() on it.

Comment: Regarding the last question, I think the cleaned_data dict is only available when a form is valid? I get an IndexError because the key does not exist.